# check if user requests his own page in asp.net mvc/angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, owin-security

I'm using asp.net mvc with angularjs for my project. How to return some extra data(smth like isOwner variable) alongside with `user` object?

```
var isOwner = false;
if(user.Alias == User.Identity.Name)
isOwner = true;)
```

On the view I want to show edit button only if user requests his own page

Here's api controller:

```
public User GetUser(String id)
{
    xRM.DAO.Model.User user = null;
    using (var db = new xRMContext())
    {
        user = db.Users
            .Include("Team").Include("Unit").Include("Location")
            .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Alias.ToLower() == id.ToLower());
    }

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return user;
}
```

and angularjs controller:

```
.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'User', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, User) {
    $scope.user = User.get({ id: $routeParams.id })
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return a viewmodel instead of the `User` model. The viewmodel should contain any properties that are needed by the view and not just expose all properties of the `User` object. For example:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    // more properties from User
    public bool IsOwner {get; set;}
}
```

You obviously need to change the `GetUser` action method so it returns `UserViewModel`, add the logic that figures out if a user is owner and map the properties from a `User` object to the viewmodel. If you find yourself mapping properties often, which can become tedious, I strongly recommend using [Automapper](http://automapper.org/).